# how to implement pagination using the SounCloud API?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been able to get all the tracks but since there are too many, I need to implement pagination. Reading through the documentation I found out that I need somehow to get the next_href. But I have not been able to accomplish that task. What I want is to be able to display 10 tracks at the time, with the option to have a next feature which would display the next 10 tracks. Here is my code, which I call from the $(document).ready(function(){getAllTracks()});
Thanks in advance...

```
var currentPage = 0;

         // Get all tracks from my profile
     function getAllTracks(){
        SC.get("/tracks", {
                  user_id: userId,
                  limit: 10,
                 linked_partitioning: currentPage      
              }, function (tracks) {

                    // Create next button
                    $('#mainContainer').append("<button id='next'>Next</button>");
                    for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
                        var className = tracks[i].title;
                        $('#mainContainer').append("<div id=" + i + " class= sermones-list></div>");

                        SC.oEmbed(tracks[i].uri, {maxwidth: "700%", maxheight: "166"} ,document.getElementById(i));
                        $("#" + i).before("<h3>"+ tracks[i].title+ " " + tracks[i].created_at +"</h3>");
                    }

                    $('#next').click(function(){
                        currentPage = currentPage + 1;
                        $('#mainContainer').empty();
                        console.log(currentPage)
                        getAllTracks();
                    });
                    console.log(currentPage)
                  // }
              });   
      } 


$(document).ready(function(){
   currentPage = 1;
   getAllTracks();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to keep track of the current page, let's call it `currentPage`. Set `currentPage` to 1 in `$(document).ready`, and substitute `currentPage` for `1` when you get the tracks.

Add in a button/link in your for loop that increments `currentPage` and calls `getAllLinks()`:

Next

Finally, you'll have to clear your container before updating.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay now I have create a global variable called currentPage and initialize it to 1 in the $(document).ready. In the linked_partitioning I substituted the 1 for the currentPage variable. I also create the button and a click handler for that button which increments the currentPage, clear my container, and calls getAllTracks() in that order. However, nothing gets display. I check the console and see that the first 10 trakcs are sucessfully being requested but are not being displayed.
Thanks again for your time and patience...

Comment: Can you post your code? That would help in debugging, thanks!

Comment: I already updated the first comment. It now has the code I was talking about

Comment: What happens when you log out the tracks? Are they getting received?

Comment: I get:
sdk.js:1 GET http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?user_id=69832010&limit=10&linked_partition…_id=f8ce83f239a589a700374d145b6f1dd5&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

However, I have noticed that when I comment out the "linked_partinioning" part, the first 10 tracks get displayed correctly.

Comment: Can you set currentPage to 1 initially and see what happens?

Comment: I get "[Object Object]" as a response. But nothing gets displayed on this screen.

Comment: I've been looking in the console and found out that the response of my SC.get () request is a collection of tracks. However, I do not know how to get that collection. It does no say in the documentation. Any idea?